# Decoding files containing hebrew characters and German eszett using iconv

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8

I have a file that I'm pretty sure is in a weird encoding. I've successfully converted similar files to utf-8 previously by assuming they were encoded in windows-1255 using iconv (`iconv -f windows-1255 -t utf-8 $file`) and this has worked successfully.

My current file contains a ß character that is throwing me off - iconv breaks when it hits this (with an "illegal input sequence" error). Is there a different kind of encoding I should be using?

Comment: `iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t utf-8 $file`?

Comment: First step is figuring out what encoding the file is using instead of guessing.

Comment: If you don't know what encoding it is in, how do you know it contains "ß"?

Comment: iconv breaks midway through a row, and if I extract that row and use a different original encoding I can see the "ß" there. It's also obvious from the context (appears in a German word).

iso-8859-15 doesn't break iconv anymore, but the Hebrew characters don't render properly if I use this.

Answer (score 1):

[WINDOWS-1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) (= Hebrew) does not know an [Eszett (ß)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F), so ICONV behaves correctly. Other legacy codepages that know that character on code point `00DF`:

- [WINDOWS-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) = Latin 2 / Central European
- [WINDOWS-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) = Latin 1 / Western European
- [WINDOWS-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) = Turkish
- [WINDOWS-1257](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257) = Baltic
- [WINDOWS-1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) = Vietnamese

Only the document owner knows which codepage is the correct one. If it's one of the [WINDOWS-125x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-125x) at all.

Comment: Thanks! From further investigation/discussion the original file appears to be some mangled combination of windows-1255 for some lines and windows-1252 for others, sadly. I think the best solution is to hack something together that handles this...